# Hook Re-render update array items from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a hook to display an array of alerts in an application. Every time I call the hook to push the array and show a new alert it works without problem, but if I want to remove this alert from the child component, invoking the parent hook function does not work.

This is the alert component. The "closeAlert" props are the one that calls the parent hook function.
The method is invoked, it removes the element I want from the array, but it does not render with the new value of the array

```
import React from 'react';
import { Alert, Button } from '@themesberg/react-bootstrap';
import { memo } from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

const Alerts = memo(({ content, closeAlert, i }) => {
  const domEl = document.getElementById('alerts')
  if (!domEl) return null

  return createPortal(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Alert
        variant="primary">

        <div className="d-flex  align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <div className="font-small">
            {content.body}
          </div>
          <Button variant="close" size="xs" onClick={() => closeAlert(i)} />
        </div>
      </Alert>
    </React.Fragment>,
    domEl
  );
})

export default Alerts;
```

This is the hook. When I call the Alerts component I pass the "handleCloseAlert" function as props. As I said in the previous point. From Alerts, it invokes this function without problem, and removes the desired "hiddenAlerts" array element, but never updates or renders it in the "RenderAlert"

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import Alerts from '../components/Alerts';

const useAlert = () => {
    const [hiddenAlerts, setHiddenAlerts] = useState([]);

    const handleShowAlert = (alertId) => {
        const hiddenAlertsUpdated = [...hiddenAlerts, alertId];
        setHiddenAlerts(hiddenAlertsUpdated);
    };

    const handleCloseAlert = (alertId) => {
        const alerts = hiddenAlerts;
        alerts.splice(alertId, 1);
        setHiddenAlerts(alerts);
    };

    const RenderAlert = () => (
        <Fragment>
            {
                hiddenAlerts.map((res, index) => {
                    return <Alerts key={index} content={res} i={index} closeAlert={handleCloseAlert}></Alerts>
                })
            }
        </Fragment>
    )

    return {
        handleShowAlert,
        handleCloseAlert,
        RenderAlert
    }
};

export default useAlert;
```

From here I invoke the hook

```
export default (props) => {
  const { handleShowAlert, RenderAlert } = useAlert();

  const open = () => {
    const alert = new AlertModal(
      "Alert test",
      '',
      Constants.TYPE_ALERT.warning
    )
    handleShowAlert(alert);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="primary" type="button" onClick={open} className="w-100">Abrir modal</Button>
      <RenderAlert>
      </RenderAlert>
    </div>
  )
}
```

From already thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem comes from the usage of `splice` function which modifies the current array, so the `hiddenAlerts` array keep the same reference. You can instead create a new array by using the `filter` function like this :

```
const handleCloseAlert = i => {
  const newAlerts = hiddenAlerts.filter((_, index) => i !== index);
  setHiddenAlerts(newAlerts);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because in your `handleCloseAlert` implementation, `alerts`  is a  reference to your state object `hiddenAlerts`.Performing a `splice` and updating state with `setHiddenAlerts(alerts)` does not trigger a state change as react doesn't see any change in the `hiddenAlerts` ( as `alerts` is also the same [reference] )

You can try the below implementation

```
 const handleCloseAlert = (alertId) => {
        setHiddenAlerts(hiddenAlerts.filter((_, index) => index !== alertId));
    };
```

Also, try to change this implementation to not depend on the array index value. Try using a library like [`uuid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)